# How can I graph execution time on Jenkins between tests with pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, performance-testing

I'd like to produce a graph of results I spit out from my build on Jenkins.

My application runs a control loop that should run as fast as possible. While it's running, I log the execution time of each iteration. After logging the application, I gather some statistics such as the 95th percentile and max execution time of the loop. I can successfully get that data into my jenkins console log.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to visualize the data. I saw the Jenkins plot-plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) but it isn't compatible with pipeline (as far as I can tell), which I would like to use for my project.

I would like to plot this data over time to track the performance of the application and make sure it doesn't degrade over time. Can someone please give some advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [2.0.0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plot-plugin/releases/tag/plot-2.0.0) version [Jenkins Plot](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) plugin is compatible with Jenkins Pipeline. You can find an example on [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) page.
You should be able to save results in any supported format convenient to you and draw plots from it.

Required pipeline plot step can be generated via [Pipeline Snippet Generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator).

For example (where `data.csv` is your input file with recorded data):

```
plot csvFileName: 'plot-23082614-ae0a-40fc-8b14-e7ce3815744b.csv', 
        csvSeries: [[displayTableFlag: false, exclusionValues: '', 
                     file: 'data.csv', inclusionFlag: 'OFF', url: '']], 
        group: 'TestGroup', style: 'line', title: 'TestTitle'
```